# Getting the location of the current file in q (kdb)

Tags: kdb

Is there a way to get the location of the current running file in q in a similar fashion then Python's `__file__`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zf-file

You can use `.z.f` for this, it contains the name of the file loaded on command line. Doesn't work for files loaded with `\l` though

```
jonny@grizzly ~ $ echo 'show .z.f' > a.q
jonny@grizzly ~ $ q a.q
KDB+ 3.5 2017.10.11 Copyright (C) 1993-2017 Kx Systems
l32/ 2()core 1945MB jonny grizzly 127.0.1.1 NONEXPIRE

`a.q
q)\\
jonny@grizzly ~ $ q
KDB+ 3.5 2017.10.11 Copyright (C) 1993-2017 Kx Systems
l32/ 2()core 1945MB jonny grizzly 127.0.1.1 NONEXPIRE

q)\l a.q
`
q)\\
```

If you need to find the location of a function loaded in a script with `\l` you can get this info from `value .z.s` in recent versions of kdb:

```
jonny@grizzly ~ $ echo 'b:{show value[.z.s]8}' > b.q
jonny@grizzly ~ $ echo 'c:{show value[.z.s]8}' > c.q
jonny@grizzly ~ $ q
KDB+ 3.5 2017.10.11 Copyright (C) 1993-2017 Kx Systems
l32/ 2()core 1945MB jonny grizzly 127.0.1.1 NONEXPIRE

q)\l b.q
q)\l c.q
q)b[]
"/home/jonny/b.q"
q)c[]
"/home/jonny/c.q"
```

Note that this behaviour is different in older versions of kdb. For reference, there is additional information available from `value .z.s`:

```
jonny@grizzly ~ $ echo 'd:{show value[.z.s]}' > d.q
jonny@grizzly ~ $ q
KDB+ 3.5 2017.10.11 Copyright (C) 1993-2017 Kx Systems
l32/ 2()core 1945MB jonny grizzly 127.0.1.1 NONEXPIRE

q)\l d.q
q)d[]
0x7733a0520002
,`x
`symbol$()
,`
k){1 .Q.s x;}
12 6 1 1
"..d"
"/home/jonny/d.q"
1
"{show value[.z.s]}"
```

See http://code.kx.com/q/ref/metadata/#value for more details

Comment: I am very sorry for my late response.  I deeply hate q but I am force to work with it.  Nevertheless, this answer is, far ahead, the best answer I got of any q related questions.  Thousand thanks.